# Data cleanup in Teradata TPT stream using informatica

Tags: stream, teradata, informatica

i am using Teradata tpt stream  connection in infomatica to load target table.problem is even if my sesssion get fail it load some Record in target table..that is because tpt stream is use row levele operation...and have to perform manually cleanup of Record ..is there any option to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no such option readily available. What you can do is to write a shell script that would connect to the database and execute a cleanup query. You can put this script in session's on failure command task option.